# How can I move this into a other class

Tags: java, class, refactoring

I am working on a Four in a row game.
But I have run into a problem with it. I have been able to make the game work. But I would like to know if I can move my public void fillBoard() and public void presentBoard() into another class. This is because I would like to make the code more organised.

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        GameMechanics game = new GameMechanics();
        game.play();
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class GameMechanics
{

    /*
    This is my local variables
    */

    public Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    public char token;
    public int column;
    public int player = 2;
    public int turn = 2;
    public int count = 0;
    public boolean gameRunning = true;

    public void play()
    {
        this.createBoard();
        //While gameRunning is true, the methods inside the { } will run, and that's the 4InARow game
        while (gameRunning)
        {
            this.presentBoard();
            this.changeTurn();
            this.dropToken();
            this.gameWon();
        }
        presentBoard();

    }

    public void gameWon()
    {
        this.winConHorizontal();
        this.winConVertical();
    }

    private char[][] board = new char[6][7];

    //Creating my board and assign "space" to all the fields in the array.
    public void createBoard() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                board[i][j] = ' ';
            }
        }
    }

    //Presents the board, it prints the board with |"space"| so it looks more like a gameboard.
    public void presentBoard() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                if (j == 0) {
                    System.out.print("|");
                }
                System.out.print(board[i][j] + "|");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public void changeTurn() {
        if (this.turn == this.player) {
            this.turn = 1;
            this.token = 'X';
        } else {
            this.turn++;
            this.token = 'O';
        }
    }

    public void dropToken() {
        System.out.println("player " + turn + ": press 1-7 to drop the token");
        column = scanner.nextInt() - 1;
        //If pressed any intValue outside the board, it will tell you to try again.
        if (column >= 7 || column <= -1)
        {
            System.out.println("place the token inside the bord");
            changeTurn();
        } else {
            //Drops the token and replace it with playerChar.
            for (int i = 5; i > -1; i--) {
                if (board[i][column] == ' ')
                {
                    board[i][column] = token;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean winConHorizontal() {

        while (gameRunning) {
            for (int i = 0; 6 > i; i ++) {
                for (int j = 0; 7 > j; j ++) {
                    if (board[i][j] == this.token) {
                        count ++;
                    } else {
                        count = 0;
                    }
                    if (count >= 4) {
                        System.out.println("player " + (turn) + " Wins!!!!");
                        gameRunning = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        return gameRunning;
    }

    public boolean winConVertical() {

        while (gameRunning) {
            for (int i = 0; 7 > i; i ++) {
                for (int j = 0; 6 > j; j ++) {
                    if (board[j][i] == this.token) {
                        count ++;
                    } else {
                        count = 0;
                    }
                    if (count >= 4) {
                        System.out.println("player " + (turn) + " Wins!!!!");
                        gameRunning = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        return gameRunning;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this : http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/66523/how-many-lines-per-class-is-too-many-in-java

Comment: BTW `fillBoard#` is missing from the code

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to do this is as follows:

1. extract your `char[][] board` into its own class, e.g. `Board`
   Said class could expose the function `char getField(int index)`
2. Extract the ,,presenting" part of your code into another class, e.g. `BoardPresenter`. Said class should have a function `presentBoard(Board board)` which internally uses `getField(int index)` of the `Board` class.

By doing this you abstract away your internal board storage mechanism while also reducing the number of responsibilities the `GameMechanics` class has (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can make another class and extend it with the current class  `GameMechanics`  and inside another class you can define the functions.

Note : This is a very simple approachable way.
Otherwise better if you manage your classes and interfaces similar to mvc model, for which you can search youtube for mvc structure java.

Comment: You could, but [would you want to](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)?